# Abuse TS339 comparator channel as a voltage multiplier

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, stability

I have multiple free channels of a TS339 amplifier remaining and would like to use one of them to multiply voltages like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6znFF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now it's a common rule that you should never use OpAmps as comparators or vice-versa, but I'm wondering whether there's any fundamental issues that prevent me from doing so here.

I need a bandwidth of 400 kHz and a gain of 5 (as visible in the circuit).

The comparator's output is open-drain and it's CMOS-based, but I assume it can operate in its linear region just as well?

The output load will be less than 100kOhms, with no capacitive load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume the output is intended to be connected to the R2/R4 node in your schematic (Edit: It has been corrected).

No, you should not do this, as it will not be stable (it will oscillate). Using an op-amp as a comparator is sometimes justified (where the input type allows it, and where precision or other factors outweigh performance), but it is rare that you can use a comparator successfully as an op-amp because of the lack of compensation. There is no access to the internal nodes to allow you to stabilize the amplifier with compensation network(s).

There is only one exception that I am aware of, and that is the ancient bipolar cousin of the chip you are using, the LM339, which can be compensated by adding a BFC (big fat capacitor) to the output. Something like 10uF, if memory serves. You end up with a rather crummy op-amp but perhaps usable in some circumstances.